# How to pronounce "Pate" for the megaphone?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In *Animal Crossing: New Leaf*, there is a megaphone item you can use to call villagers over to you if they are outside and not too far away.

It works fine for me for most villagers, but I cannot get it to work for Pate. I have tried the following pronunciations, all while she is visible so I know it's not an issue of distance:

- Pate (rhymes with "eight")
- Pa-tay
- Patty
- Pat
- Patey (rhymes with "eighty")

The [Animal Crossing wiki says](https://animalcrossing.fandom.com/wiki/Pate)

> her name should most likely be pronounced "Pa-tay"

but that doesn't sound definitive, and I've tried that pronunciation and it doesn't seem to work. I've also found forum threads where people speculate on the pronunciation, but again it just sounds like speculation (no one mentions the megaphone).

I know the 3DS microphone isn't the best and I'm sure *New Leaf* doesn't have the most advanced voice-recognition algorithms, but it'd be nice to at least have an idea of how I should be trying to pronounce it so I can hopefully eventually get it to work.